# With R, how do I get a random number from a varying vector that can be of length 1

Tags: r, random, sample

I'm using sample(2:ncol(matrix),1) to get the number of a random column in my matrix, excluding column 1. The matrix increases in size as my loop iterates. It works as it should, except that when the number of columns is 2, instead of automatically returning 2 with a 100% probability, it sometimes returns 1. That's because when the length of the object from which to sample is 1, sample considers it to range from 1 to that number. How can I avoid this, or is there a better function for me to use?

Thanks

I've tried sample(2:ncol(matrix),1), but when ncol(matrix)=2, it can return 1, which should not happen for my code.

Comment: `sample(seq(2:ncol(matrix)),1)`?

Comment: `sample((ncol(matrix)-1),1)` should also work, though if `matrix` has only one column it will return `0` deterministically.

Comment: You can also handle it using a condition `if (ncol(matrix) > 2) {
  col_num <- sample(2:ncol(matrix), 1)
} else {
  col_num <- 2}`

Comment: @r2evans neat way around it in this case, but I think OP needs `sample((ncol(matrix)-1),1) + 1`

Comment: This behavior is called out on the `?sample` documentation. The solution proposed in the documentation is `resample <- function(x, ...) x[sample.int(length(x), ...)]`

Comment: Ummm .... what happened to user20650's answer? It and all comments related to it disappeared. @GregorThomas, any idea? If it's a moderator-hammer, why?

Comment: @r2evans no clue here.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the that the sample() function works when the sequence to be sample have length one.
Example the input `sample(c(1,3,5))` will return a number of the set {1,3,5}, while `sample(4)` will return a number of the set {1,2,3,4} (just like the function `sample.int(4)` would do).

When the length of vector is variable, it is advisable to use the function sample.int() instead.

Note that the sequence 2:ncol(matrix) has length equal to ncol(matrix) - 1.

The following code will return an random value of this sequence, independently of the number of rows of your matrix (assuming that the matrix always have 2 or more columns).

```
 index = sample.int(ncol(matrix)-1)  # get an random index 
 (2:ncol(matrix))[index] # get the random value in the sequence.
```